# CakePHP set redirect parameters using an array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am writing some simple redirects in CakePHP 2.4.2 and came across one that stumped me a bit.

How can I redirect to another view with the same passedArgs? It seems like it should be simple, but I must be overlooking something. I tried this:

```
$this->redirect(array_merge(array('action' => 'index',$this->params['named'])));
```

The debug output seems correct:

```
array(
'action' => 'index',
(int) 0 => array(
    'this' => 'url',
    'and' => 'stuff'
)
)
```

My desired outcome is that

```
view/this:url/and:stuff
```

redirects to

```
index/this:url/and:stuff
```

but now it just sends me to

```
index/
```

Not sure what I am missing here, perhaps I have deeper configuration issues - although it's not a terribly complicated app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passed params (numeric keys) use array_merge.
But since you use named params, which have a string based key, you can leverage PHP basics:

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index') + $this->request->params['named']));
```

This adds all array values from the named params except for action, which is already in use here (and hence should not be overwritten anyway). So the priority is clear, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cake expects a flat array of parameters, so you need to use `array_merge` to add in extra arrays to it on the sides. Try this:

```
$this->redirect(array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['named']));
```

... or using your original variable `$passedArgs`:

```
$this->redirect(array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->passedArgs));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution will be used `persist` attribute in `Router::connect()`?